# Cursor: pointer; on svg element is not working

Tags: html, css, svg, mouse-cursor

In my website i use svg elements. Sometimes i need them to be clickable, therefore i want pointer cursor over them.

However adding css class or style

```
cursor: pointer;
```

not work.

That's the example element

```
<object id="male2" type="image/svg+xml" data="course/ani/male2.svg" style="left: 87px; bottom: 56px;" es-character="male2"></object>
```

It seems like it just not worki with svg. Anyone know how to fix, or how to go around it?

Comment: Please demo the problem.

Comment: I don't see `cursor:pointer;` in your css..?

Comment: What are you attaching the cursor: pointer rule to?  If you just have it in your css by itself, it's not going to work.

Comment: As i wrote in question. I tried adding class 'buttonMode' with cursor:pointer, and then add this class to this object. I tried also adding this property to id (#male2{cursor:pointer;}); Adding this straight to style also not work. I found similiar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563293/cursor-pointer-not-showing-when-using-an-svg-image-in-internet-explorer but it not work for me..

Comment: As the [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563293/cursor-pointer-not-showing-when-using-an-svg-image-in-internet-explorer) explains, the cursor style has to be defined *in the embedded SVG*.  If you are setting styles on the `<object>` element (with `id="male2"), they will not have an effect because (unlike an image) the object is interactive.  When the cursor is over the object, it is controlled by the styles in the SVG document, not by the styles in the main web page.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As AmeliaBR's comment indicates, you should add this style inside the SVG `<object>`.

And unless your SVG is very simple, you may have the same issue I had: only seeing a pointer when you are hovering over one of the shapes in the SVG, but not when you're between shapes.

(In some cases you might want that behavior, but for a wordmark, for example, you typically want the whole rectangle to be clickable, not just the individual letters.)

To make the whole rectangle clickable, add `svg { cursor: pointer; }`. If you just want specific elements clickable, name them by class:

```
<svg ...>
  <style>
    svg { cursor: pointer; } /* whole rectangle */

    /* OR */

    .element-name { cursor: pointer; } /* specific elements */
  </style>
  ...
</svg>
```

Comment: this is not working with SVG components in Nextjs for some reason

Answer (score 10):

I think this is the easiest solution among the others:

1. wrap svg into `<a>` or anything else that will receive clicks:

```
<a href="#">
    <object>
        <embed src="img.svg"></embed>
    </object>
</a>
```

2. remove pointer events from `<object>` so all clicks will be triggered on the wrapper element:

```
object {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: @brgs as far as I remember worked fine for me, do you have an example to look in?

Comment: Same scenario as the question, just .myClass a object { pointer-events:none; /*size margin display*/ } works for me.

Comment: Setting `pointer-events: none` on the `<object>` tag fixed my problem

Answer (score 3):

If adding "`cursor: pointer`" directly to the `svg` element does not work, you can either try to add an transparent element (Pseudo elements directly on the `object` tag do not work) with the same dimensions as the SVG which is absolutely positioned over the SVG.

```css
a.svg-cursor:before {
content: "";
display: block;
position: absolute;
background-color: transparent;
cursor: pointer;
/* plus width and height of the SVG */
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="svg-cursor">
<object id="male2" type="image/svg+xml" data="course/ani/male2.svg" es-character="male2"></object>
</a>
```

Or you can take an `img` instead of `object` and add the "`cursor: pointer`"-style to the img:

`<img id="male2" src="course/ani/male2.svg" style="left: 87px; bottom: 56px;" alt="Description" />`

Answer (score 2):

To style individual elements in your SVG you can either use Javascript or use CSS inside the image in the defs tag or reference an external stylesheet.

```
<svg ...>
  <defs>
    <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
      .myfigureclass {
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    ]]></style>
  </defs>
```

Check [this link](https://www.sitepoint.com/svg-styling-with-css/) for more information.

You can also use an external stylesheet for your SVG like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.svg.css" ?>

<svg
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   ...>
(...)
</svg>
```

Check [this link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-and-css.html#external-css-style-sheets) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest solutions may be to use img tag instead of object tag

```
<img src="course/ani/male2.svg" style="left: 87px; bottom: 56px;"  />
```

although, ideally you can embed the svg in the html. 
That doesn't let you cache the svg files, so I found using javascript to load the svg file as text and insert into the DOM allowed for caching and still got the SVG directly into the DOM so it could use all the css styles from your page.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem too and solved it with a style sheet fix to the link style.  Add **cursor: pointer**; there. i.e.

```
a { cursor: pointer; }
```