# Polymer paper-input suffix not working as expected

Tags: input, polymer, paper-elements, suffix

I have a paper-input in which I nested a SVG through an `<object>` element using the `suffix` attribute.

Now I want to call a function through tap on the `<object>` element.

[Docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input)

So here is my code:

HTML

```
<paper-input class="border" label="Deine Email-Adresse" no-label-float>
    <object suffix data="../icons/arrow.svg" type="image/svg+xml" on-tap="_subscribeNewsletter">
        <!--<img src="fallback.jpg" />-->
    </object>
</paper-input>
```

CSS

```
.newsletter-input paper-input object {
    height : 60px; 
    width : 100px; 
    position: absolute; 
    right: -10px; 
    margin-top: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

on-tap isn't fired nor is the cursor displayed as a pointer.

The input itself is nested inside a `.newsletter-input` div and both , the div and the input have some more styles applied to them, if needed I can add these to, just let me know.

Any Ideas?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you implement your _subscribeNewsletter method? I tried - and it worked.

Comment: @sebastian for now i only log a message to the console in the function:  _subscribeNewsletter : function(){
        console.log('_subscribeNewsletter');
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
<paper-input class="border" label="Deine Email-Adresse" no-label-float>
    <img suffix src="../icons/arrow.svg" onerror="this.src='fallback.png'" on-tap="_subscribeNewsletter" />
</paper-input>
```

Tested and worked like a charm :-)

Comment: Ok with img tag i'm able to fire the function, but i cant resize my svg to the proper size

Comment: oups sorry my bad, just had a thinking error. yup works with img tag. thx. but i still have no clue what the problem is with object..

Answer (score 0):

Your styling is not working because your `object` is ultimately rendered in `dom` of `paper-input`. So your selector is wrong. If you keep `object` as only selector for styling it'll work properly.

```
object {
            height : 60px; 
            width : 100px; 
            position: absolute; 
            right: -10px; 
            margin-top: 3px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

And i don't see why you `tap` listener should not work. It's working properly for me

Comment: Ya i too noticed that. If you give wrong image address then it works. Maybe it's something related to `object` not sure

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672936/cursor-pointer-on-svg-element-is-not-working)

Comment: I'll take a nearer look at it and try to understand what the problem is with object thx, for now sebastians answer works for me